Setting gud-gdb-command-name in .dir-locals.el
For my current project I have been trying to configure it so I don't need to explicitly type compile and debug commands each time I start a new emacs session.
In my .dir-locals.el file I have:
((nil . ((eval . (set (make-local-variable 'project-path) (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")))))
(c++-mode . ((compile-command . (concat project-path "rest of my compile command"))
(gud-gdb-command-name . (concat project-path "rest of my debug command)))))

This works until I do m-x gdb where I get the message: Wrong type argument: characterp, concat however compiling gives the correct command.
Replacing (concat project-path "rest of my debug command) with the full command resolves this issue but will break if I change my folder structure.
I don't have a huge amount of experience in lisp, and don't understand why concat is producing the wrong type when I run gdb.

The general format for .dir-locals.el is described here:

C-hig (emacs)Directory Variables
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables

The file is data rather than code, so nothing is evaluated by default.  To evaluate code, you must use the special pseudo variable name eval, as described at:

C-hig (emacs)Specifying File Variables
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LocalVariables

You've already done this in one place:
(eval . (set (make-local-variable 'project-path) (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")))

which you could simplify to:
(eval . (setq-local project-path (locate-dominating-file default-directory ".dir-locals.el")))

but you didn't use eval here:
(compile-command . (concat project-path "rest of my compile command"))

And so this is setting the buffer-local value of compile-command to a list value (a list with the symbol concat as its first element, resulting in your error "Wrong type argument: characterp, concat").
Instead, do this like your first case:
(eval . (setq-local compile-command (concat project-path "rest of my compile command")))

